# Swift 4 : Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift4, xcode9

I'm using Xcode 9, Swift 4.

I'm trying to show an image in ImageView from URL using below code :

```
func getImageFromUrl(sourceUrl: String) -> UIImage {
        let url = URL(string: sourceUrl)
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url!)
        let data = Data(dictionary: dict!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        return image
}
```

But I got an error in `let image = UIImage(data: data!)`.

The compiler says :

> Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because you have a class named "Data".

Answer (score 3):

Please check any class name has **Data** (that you have created)in the project.
Due to class name conflicts, swift may not be able to identify Foudation's Data class or your Project's Data class.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// Returns nil if image data is not correct or some network error has happened
func getImageFromUrl(sourceUrl: String) -> UIImage? {
  if let url = URL(string: sourceUrl) {
    if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf:url) {
      return UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a network call.  I had to explicitly type `Foundation.Data` to make sure there wasn't some weird namespace thing going on.

```
  func getMediaItems(completion: @escaping (Foundation.Data?, ResponseError?) -> ()) {
         let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
         let url = self.makeURL()
         let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: 
              { data, response, error in
                   if let imageData = data {
                        completion(data, nil) // had error here
             //etc, etc...
```

Pretty annoying.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something or it's Swift 4 bug but it seemed to solve the issue.  Without "Foundation" I got the same area at `completion(data,nil)`
(ps. do not use this code as it's a sample and doesn't include error handling)